# Recover holomorphic function $Imf(z)=g(|z|^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions

How to find all analytic functions $f$ such that $\operatorname{Im}f(z)=g(|z|^2)$, where $g$ is a real-valued function? Cauchy-Riemann is not very helpful as $g$ is not given explicitly.

Comment: Analytic where?

Comment: On $ \mathbb{C}$

Comment: Then say that in your hypotheses, or say $f$ is entire.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: This would imply $\text { Im } f(z)$ is constant on the unit circle.

Comment: Thank you for the hint but I am not being able to use it. Using Cauchy-Riemann in polar form yields u =0. Which is strange and does not agree with the conditions. Can you suggest something else?

Comment: Don't forget $\text { Im } f(z)$ is harmonic.

Comment: Thanks. Got $g(r^2)=Ce^{2r}+C_1$

Comment: Hmm ... I got $\text { Im }f(z)$ is constant.

Comment: on a circle of given radius indeed it is.

Comment: So this function is harmonic everywhere and constant on the unit circle. Now use the maximum principle

Comment: Correction I got $Imf(z)= \frac{-C}{r}+C_1$ after using laplace equation in polar co-ordinates for $Imf(z)$, so I have to imply from the maximum principle that $C=0$?

Comment: I don't really know what you're doing. You have a harmonic function on the whole plane that is constant on the unit circle. Therefore it is constant.

Comment: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) Check the situation where there are arbitrarily close points at which the function takes greater values.

Comment: I don't know why you're confused. A function harmonic on $\mathbb C$ that is constant on the unit circle is everywhere constant!

Comment: Why does wikipedia say either the function is constant or at arbitrarily close points the function can take greater values?

Comment: We are using the maximum principle for real harmonic functions.